# Edit XML file in a directory

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to edit multiple config.xml file inside different directories of folders, using a python script. I am looking for a specific tag value then change it with a new value.

i have created an array and am using ElementTree api.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

d1 = r'/home/user/temp/a/'
d2 = r'/home/user/temp/b/'
d3 = r'/home/user/temp/c/' 
d4 = r'/home/user/temp/d/'
d5 = r'/home/user/temp/f/'

data = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5]

for dir in data:

    tree = ET.ElementTree(os.path.join(dir + 'config.xml'))
    root = tree.getroot()

    for Element in tree.iter(tag='url'):
        print(Element.text)
        Element.text = str("new value")
        tree.write('config.xml')
```

This is the xml am trying to modify

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@2.4.2">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
     <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <url>happy changes</url>
       </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
     <branches>
       <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
         <name>refactor</name>
     </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
<doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false
</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <extensions>
      <hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.PerBuildTag/>
    </extensions>
  </scm>
```

This the error message

```
for Element in tree.iter(tag='url'):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 620, in 
  iter
  return self._root.iter(tag)
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

Comment: so what is your question ?

Comment: Like @murphy1310 said; what is your question? Are you getting an error? Is the value not updating? Also, an example of a config.xml file will most likely be necessary. It doesn't need to be a full example, just enough for us to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My apologies, this is the error message 
     for Element in tree.iter(tag='url'):
     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 620, in iter
     return self._root.iter(tag)  
     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to provide the full path name in the .write() call? Like this:

```
tree.write(os.path.join(dir + 'config.xml'))
```

Otherwise all your config.xml files will simply be written to your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

`ElementTree` expects an `Element` object as argument, not a file name with XML source code.  You need to parse the file with the `parse()` function of the ElementTree API.

You need the full path + file name for writing the result file and actually use `os.path.join()` to concatenate the path and the file name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def main():
    path_names = [
        '/home/user/temp/a',
        '/home/user/temp/b',
        '/home/user/temp/c',
        '/home/user/temp/d',
        '/home/user/temp/e',
    ]
    for path in path_names:
        filename = os.path.join(path, 'config.xml')
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        for element in tree.iter('url'):
            print(element.text)
            element.text = 'new value'
        tree.write(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```